# link current nodejs api listening to port localhost:8080 to angular which is localhost:4200

Tags: node.js, api, backend, angular6

recently my project was on localhost:8080 and the api service posted below worked and listened to that port. now i madea change to angular and want to change it so that it listens to the angular project which runs on localhost:4200. can someone please tell me what i change in the code below to make that happen. Thanks!

```
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('_helpers/jwt');
const errorHandler = require('_helpers/error-handler');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use(jwt());

// api routes
app.use('/users', require('./users/users.controller'));

// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// start server
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 80 : 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing at the moment. To clarify, the API is running on port 8080 and the client application is running on port 4200? If so, what exactly is the issue? Is the client application sending requests to 8080 or not?

Comment: @Boaz sorry for the confusion, the application was running on localhost:8080 and now its running on localhost:4200 and i am not sure what to change to make it communicate with the api as i am new to nodejs and angular

Comment: The backend appears to be configured correctly and listening to requests on 80. If the client app changed its port, it’s probably attempting to send requests on the same port - 4200. Either change the app to send requests on 80, or move the API to 4200 as well.

Comment: @Boaz thanks but can you please tell me how as i am new and am not sure how.

Comment: How to which option? If this code is going to production, changing either could have implications.

Comment: Also, following your update it appears the API runs on 4000 when in development.

Comment: @Boaz how to move the api to run on localhost:4200